# .NET and Skinny Controllers/Fat Models Concept

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I've been reading about "skinny controllers, fat models", and I see a lot of these implementations are Ruby and other languages.  I don't see many implementations in .NET, though I'm not sure if that is because I can't find some examples of people implementing it.  So, is the concept of skinny controllers and fat models one that's popular with .NET?

Thanks.

Comment: It is one of the philosophies of ASP.NET MVC and does not force you to follow it. By doing it so, you won't put to much logic into your controller and this would make your unit testing better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft does not (as far as I know) enforce this pattern, but I personally use it in all my ASP.NET MVC projects to provide better separation of concerns.

I guess it's more a matter of personal taste.